# PHP store random word in string to use multiple times

Tags: php

```
public function generateRandomString($length = 16) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
         $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

I'm looking for a way to store this in a variable. For an example: `$random = $this->generateRandomString();` and use this variable over and over again, without it changing the value. How can I do this?

Comment: Set a property in your class , `public $this->random`

Comment: you can use file, db, memcache, redis or my open source project https://github.com/Halayem/ANYEM

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Calling the function? Assigning its return value to a variable? Keeping that variable around? Persisting that variable across multiple requests?

Comment: store value in global variable

Comment: create a local static variable and perform generation only on the first invokation. On the consecutive invokations just return that variable

Comment: Is your question how to make the variable persistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property in your class:

```
Class MyClass {

   private $myRandomString;

   public function generateRandomString($length = 16) {
       $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
       $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
       $randomString = '';
       for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
         $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
       }
       return $randomString;
    }

    public function generate() {
         $this->myRandomString = $this->generateRandomString();
    }

    public function fetchRandomString(){
         return $this->myRandomString;
    }

}

$myClass = new MyClass(); 
$myClass->generate(); //Puts the random value in `private $myRandomString`

$myValue = $myClass->fetchRandomString(); //Returns the random string created
$myAnotherValue = $myClass->fetchRandomString(); //Returns the random string created (still same value)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is the revised version with less function calls.

```
class NumberGenerator {
   private $length = 16;
   private $myRandomString = null;

   function __construct($length){
     $this->length = $length;
   }

   public function generateRandomString() {
       $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
       $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
       $randomString = '';
       for ($i = 0; $i < $this->length; $i++) {
         $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
       }
       return $randomString;
   }

    public function fetchRandomString(){
        if($this->myRandomString === null){
           $this->myRandomString = $this->generateRandomString(); 
        }
         return $this->myRandomString;
    }
}


//usage
$myClass = new NumberGenerator (16); 
$randomStr = $myClass->fetchRandomString();
echo $randomStr;      //example output: CqaLEYILzxLbWPDw
```